# Mongo how to update a field if another array's last element meet a criteria

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-update

I have documents like

```
{
'need_to_update': 'not_update_yet',
'array' : [
     {'check' : 1, 'other': 'not_related'},
     {'check' : 3, 'other': 'not_related'}
]
}

{
'need_to_update': 'not_update_yet',
'array' : [
     {'check' : 1, 'other': 'not_related'},
     {'check' : 3, 'other': 'not_related'},
     {'check' : 20, 'other': 'not_related'}
]
}
```

The array length is not fixed, I want to check the last element's 'check' field. If it is larger than 10, I need to update the document's 'need_to_update'. Hope my description doesn't make any misunderstanding.

So only the second document is updated in the example, and the documents after the update should be:

```
{
'need_to_update': 'not_update_yet',
'array' : [
     {'check' : 1, 'other': 'not_related'},
     {'check' : 3, 'other': 'not_related'}
]
}

{
'need_to_update': 'updated',
'array' : [
     {'check' : 1, 'other': 'not_related'},
     {'check' : 3, 'other': 'not_related'},
     {'check' : 20, 'other': 'not_related'}
]
}
```

Comment: It's a common ask. The solution is to reverse the array as you update it, so the "last" element is actually the "first" always, and there are modifiers to `$push` which do this. Point being you cannot ask for the "last" element in a standard query expression, but you can ask for "first", which is simply the `0` index.

Answer (score 0):

try this query for update same

```
var bulk = db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp(),
counter = 0;
db.collection.find({}).forEach(
    function(doc) {
      var array = doc.array;
      if (array != null && array != undefined) {
        var lastObj = array[array.length - 1];
        var check = lastObj.check;
        bulk.find( { "array.check": check } ).update( { $set: { "need_to_update": "updated" } } );
        counter++;
    if (counter % 1000 == 0) {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    }
      }
    }
);
if (counter % 1000 != 0) { bulk.execute(); }
```